# Cannot login to UbuntuOne since upgrade to 11.10

Tags: ubuntu-one

When I start UbuntuOne on 11.10 with the same ID and password I used to have in Ubuntu 11.04 this error message appears:

Method "CreateItem" with signature "a{sv}(oayay)b" on interface "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" does't exist

And I cannot sign in or connect anyway. I heard there are some bug fixed having been released, but I do not know how to use them. Can anyone help,please?

Answer (score 1):

I had to open the Muon Package manager, searched on Ubuntu One, selected everything that was not for debugging and installed.  After, I went to "Settings", and found a "Ubuntu One"
option.  I selected it and it ran the installer.